# show desktop in gnome-classic

Tags: gnome-classic

I am trying to add a "Show Desktop" button on the panel. <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + RightClick does not work on Gnome Classic. Does anyone know how can I add this button to show the desktop? Also, assigning the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in the keyboards / Shortcut did not work.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
I am a beginner in Xwindow, but proficient in terminal.
Since I am using a pretty old machine, unity and compiz have failed to deliver the performance. gnome-classic has been the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> ( Under *SystemSettings -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> KeyboardShortcuts -> Navigation -> HideAllNormalWindows* is the answer for the show desktop shortcut atleast. I still haven't found any way to put an icon on the panel though.